# How to get all entities in the model and serialise those into xml?

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer, entity-framework-core

I'm using code-first and Entity framework core.

Is there a way to get all the classes/entities from the database model and automatically serialise all individual classes?

Currently I have approach this problem by creating a class to import and export individual classes to xml file format, however I would like to do this automatically. As long as my **code-first model** is properly marked with `[DataMember]` and `[DataContract]` annotations.

Here's my current approach:

```
public void ExportDatabase(DbContext database)
{
    //TODO: find out if mapping this database and automatically go trought all the entities is possible

    var exportChannel = new XmlExportChannel();
    var saveLocation = exportChannel.SelectSaveLocation();
    var entities = database.Model.GetEntityTypes();
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var fileName = saveLocation + "\\" + entity.Name + ".xml";

        exportChannel.SaveObject(fileName, entity.GetType(), database.XXXX);
    }
}
```

I still somehow need the access to the database class property? and the proper `type` required by the `DataContractSerializer` [msdn-link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

**EDIT:** The goal is to save the data contained in the database.

Comment: Do you want to serialize the class definitions, or instances thereof representing the data contained in the database?

Comment: the data contained inside the database.

Comment: Have you tried using Reflection to identify the classes? If you are using the Repository pattern, you could get away with simply using Get() to retrieve the data. There are more questions to be answered though. For example, would you want to retrieve the data in relational state (i.e. using navigational properties) or would you export each table separately? Do you have any tables that are represented by abstract classes? What about table inheritance, as this could lead to partial data duplication in your export?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Here are some answers: I'm using repository pattern following [this implementation](https://youtu.be/rtXpYpZdOzM) and at the moment I am serialising every class(entity) and its data as an individual xml-file. Then while importing reconstruction all the navigation relations (might not be the best way). However, I'm quite new with this topic so examples to guide me into right direction are always highly appreciated!.